# Using the word "is" in Function Names

Tags: function

Does using the word "is" in a function name classify this function as something magical, like an accessor, mutator, or constructor? Someone asked me and my initial response was likely no, but am open to being wrong.

So... Am I wrong? In any language?

Comment: This is possibly opinion based, but is likely an agreed naming convention (coding standard) for checking a boolean result. For example `isVerified()` might return true/false based on the value of verified, whether the verified value is based on a DB field, and/or some variable. Another could be `isDeleted()`, where a similar value check would be performed for a deleted field/variable, etc. As the proposed answer suggests, could simply be a readability factor.

Comment: There is a great stack exchange site for code review question like this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ try there you will find people that love this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the languages I have dealt with, as long as it is part of the name, it has no function other than readability. (Sorry I would make this a comment, but I am unable to do so)

OOP Languages I have dealt with:
JavaScript
Java
python
C++
C